# grab img src value using html agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get value of img src image link from following html. I already tried c# like bellow but this failed to grab the link. Whats wrong i am doing in c#. Anyone can help me?

C#:

```
Picture = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='imgTagWrapperId']/img").Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Html:

```
<div id="imgTagWrapperId" class="imgTagWrapper" style="height: 700px;">
                <img alt="PET N PET 1080 Counts Large Green Dog Waste Bags Unscented 60 Rolls Doggie Refill Bags" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61xdgCf5UBL._SX679_.jpg" data-old-hires="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61xdgCf5UBL._SL1001_.jpg" class="a-dynamic-image  a-stretch-vertical" id="landingImage" data-a-dynamic-image="{&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61xdgCf5UBL._SX466_.jpg&quot;:[466,466],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61xdgCf5UBL._SX569_.jpg&quot;:[569,569],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61xdgCf5UBL._SX425_.jpg&quot;:[425,425],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61xdgCf5UBL._SY355_.jpg&quot;:[355,355],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61xdgCf5UBL._SY450_.jpg&quot;:[450,450],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61xdgCf5UBL._SX679_.jpg&quot;:[679,679],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61xdgCf5UBL._SX522_.jpg&quot;:[522,522]}" style="max-width:679px;max-height:679px;">
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the code that includes the original url?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0192NCGKM here is the page which i am trying to grab data from

Comment: I see Run-time exception (line 13): 'gzip' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
Parameter name: name